# How can you avoid getting this exception in QT Bluetooth for Android?

Tags: android, qt, bluetooth, qml

The app insists on enabling geolocation services, but this is not necessary. How can you get around this limitation?

Android SDK 30
Qt QML 5.15

**qt.bluetooth.android: Search not possible due to turned off Location service**

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/why-do-i-need-to-turn-on-location-services-to-pair-with-a-bluetooth-device that suggests this isn't Qt-specific

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks!